# Is there a way to dynamically bind Angular directives?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I'm building a component that should be as reusable as possible. The current case is a modal which should allow the developer to show/hide the allowed buttons (primary:confirm, secondary:cancel).

We have to use a style library that works with directives.
I tried using a loop to add all buttons and set the directive dynamically. This doesn't work though. Simply "nothing" happens.

```
<button
  *ngFor="let button of buttons"
  [attr.primary-button]="button.type === 'primary'"
  [attr.secondary-button]="button.type === 'secondary'"
  (click)="..."
  [class]="button.class"
  [disabled]="button.disabled"
>
  {{ button.text }}
</button>
```

I'm aware that a directive is not an attribute but couldn't find any other ideas for this problem.

Comment: Would using a config object contain the various configuration options for the button be an option? If you want to dynamically add classes you can use `[ngClass]="{'primary': isPrimary, 'secondary': !isPrimary}"`

Comment: @MaartenDev The class part actually does work. It's just about the attributes.

Comment: Ah ok, not sure if is possible. Libraries like material ui use classes to set primary/secondary styling. The classes are added when providing the type.

Comment: What happens if you remove the "attr" part? According to [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-directive?file=app%2Fhighlight.directive.ts) example it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this behaviour is not supported by Angular, it is however on their [roadmap](https://angular.io/guide/roadmap#support-adding-directives-to-host-elements).

As a workaround, you would need to actually separate the buttons using `*ngIf`. Not ideal, (or very elegant for that matter) but it [does work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bbvx7g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let button of buttons">
  <button
    *ngIf="button.type === 'primary'"
    [class]="button.class"
    [disabled]="button.disabled"
    primaryButton
  >
    {{ button.text }}
  </button>

  <button
    *ngIf="button.type === 'secondary'"
    [class]="button.class"
    [disabled]="button.disabled"
    secondaryButton
  >
    {{ button.text }}
  </button>
</ng-container>
```

There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785) for this on Github, which has been active since 2016.